Access VBA/SQL statement not pulling through combobox value
I'm having trouble trying to get the value from a combobox returned in a VBA SQL statement.
The combobox is called [Customer Purchase Order] and the query is Qry_MHR_v1_Filter
I think i need to add .Column to the end of it, but stops the sql working...
Any suggestions on how to get a comboox value into recordset?
 Dim Testing As Integer
Dim Cnter As Integer
Dim Jnum2 As String
Dim strSQL2 As String
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim POnum As String


    strSQL2 = "SELECT [Job Number] , Qry_MHR_v1_Filter.[Customer Purchase Order] FROM Qry_MHR_v1_Filter WHERE [Packed] = True And [MHRSnt]= False And [SndEml] = True "
 
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)
   Testing = 0
           Cnter = 1
With rs2
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
        .MoveLast
        .MoveFirst
        While (Not .EOF)
        MsgBox (Testing)
        Testing = Testing + Cnter
        Jnum2 = rs2![Job Number]
        POnum = rs2![Customer Purchase Order]
        


Concatenate the combobox value into the SELECT clause and give it a column name. Replace FormName with the name of the form that has the combobox.
    Dim strCPO as String 

    strCPO = Me.[Customer Purchase Order]
or 
    strCPO  = Forms![formname]![Customer Purchase Order]
    
    strSQL2 =    "SELECT [Job Number] , '" & strCPO  & "' AS [Customer Purchase Order] FROM Qry_MHR_v1_Filter WHERE [Packed] = True AND [MHRSnt]= False AND [SndEml] = True"

If your combobox has the value abc then the string will evaluate as:
SELECT [Job Number] , 'abc' AS [Customer Purchase Order] FROM Qry_MHR_v1_Filter WHERE [Packed] = True AND [MHRSnt]= False AND [SndEml] = True

If your combobox has values like "O'Brian" then you will need to replace any single quote chr with 2 single quotes via Replace(FormName.[Customer Purchase Order],"'","''")
If you have alot of scenarios like this in your app then consider using a function to properly delimit all data types for SQL Trying to use variables as values vba to sql

Hi Bart, Still no joy I tired both approaches The first approach adding the form name returned an object required error and the second approach using 'abc' Its now returning 'abc' as the PO number..
The format of the values in the combobox is a combination of letters and numbers but no fancy punctuation just a number normally with P in front something like P93847
(thanks for help in this... something so simple but its not playing ball)

If your code is on the same form as the combobox you can use Me.[Customer Purchase Order]. Otherwise you may need to use Forms![formname]![Customer Purchase Order] to reference the combobox value.
